# Using 5V and ground for fan with PoE+ HAT

Tags: gpio, pi-4, poe

I have a 10" rack with 5 rpi 4B devices. All rpis have a PoE+ HAT. The rack supports the addition of 2 fans, which each require a 5V and ground connection.

I noticed that the GPIO pins don't stick all the way through the PoE+ HAT, which makes it not possible to plug in the 5V and ground into the correct GPIO port.

Is there any way I can connect the fan?

I don't have room for adding the connector with extra long pins that would go through the HAT.

I did notice that there's a little bit of exposed pin between the rpi and HAT, but I prefer not having to solder the wires on.

Is there anywhere that sells slide-on female-to-female t-splitters that would fit between the rpi and HAT?
If not, could I use any of the other ports with an adapter?

Answer (score 0):

I have seen similar devices advertised. I was incredulous that anyone would make such a device and what purpose it would serve.

Who would buy 5 HATS (each costing twice the price of a regular power supply) when you could get a 5V 15A supply for much less.

The HAT may be a useful tool to remotely power a Pi but 5 at one location??

If you study the schematics and look at the board you will see Test Points for 5V (TP 1,2,3) & Gnd (TP 7,8,9,12) which are simple to solder.

Comment: I specifically mentioned a preference not to solder. Also, I didn't mind paying a little extra to prevent the cable clutter. I needed the network connection anyways.